# NSInvalidArgumentException when posting notification

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, notifications, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am trying to use the notification system in order to have a detail view in a Splitviewcontroller to update the tableview. I declared the notification as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushView:) name:@"pushView" object:nil];
```

and the selector itself:

```
- (void) pushView:(UIViewController *) viewController {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now, in the detailview I create the view-controller and call create the notification:

```
   ArticleTableViewController *articleTableView  = [[ArticleTableViewController alloc] initWithCategory:catInt];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushView" object:articleTableView];
```

I assumed that that would work, but I get the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSConcreteNotification
>   setParentViewController:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5a3a290'

So I guess I am doing something wrong in how including the detailViewController in the notification to be used to push in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method definition for handling the notification seems to be wrong.

```
- (void) pushView:(UIViewController *) viewController
```

should be,

```
- (void) pushView:(NSNotification *) notification
```

The actual notification is passed as the argument, not any view controllers. To achieve what you want, try the following.

```
- (void) pushView:(NSNotification *) notification

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"ViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

And while posting the notification,

```
    ArticleTableViewController *articleTableView  = [[ArticleTableViewController alloc] initWithCategory:catInt];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:articleTableView forKey:@"ViewController"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushView" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. But how would I implement that in this scenario, i.e. can I use a notification to pass the view-controller to the splitviewcontroller?

Comment: Great, it is just the object in the notification, works great!